# how to avoid conflict of two jqueries in same page?

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have two jqueries in my page.
One for image slider and another for map nearest places search.
Having two document.ready functions and two different .js files.
At present only one functionality working.
Please reply me if any solution?

```
 $(function(){
            $('.chkbox').click(function(){
                $(':checkbox').attr('checked',false);
                $('#'+$(this).attr('id')).attr('checked',true);
                search_types(map.getCenter());
            });

        });
<script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function (){
                $("#pikame").PikaChoose({carousel:true});
            });
    </script>
```

I have these two functions and different js files.

Comment: Try this at the top.   $.noConflict();

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: i tried $.noConflict(); but not working. only one function is working. please give any other solutions .Thank you

Comment: Anybody have solution for this problem? Please help me friends.